# How to detect which signature field is linked to the corresponding btn at run time?

Tags: itext7

I'd a document [document.pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gws1sO6qIIOqlCe1BXqQcCR3okQWFQ0c/view?usp=sharing) which has some signature fields and their corresponding btn visible on the document. Using `iText7`, while iterating over the fields I can see both the sign btns and signature fields. How I can detect that which signature field is linked to corresponding sign btn at run time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How I can detect that which signature field is linked to corresponding sign btn at run time?

There is no link between button and signature field in the sense of a simple and specified entry in the button dictionary.

All there is, is the JavaScript code executed when a button is clicked, e.g. for `btn_sign`:

```js
//Make sure the form is valid and then allow the signature.
if (ValidateForm() == true)
{
    if (this.dirty == true)
    {
        app.alert("Please save the form before signing, to ensure the proper saved name!");
    }
    else
    {
        app.alert("Please click anywhere in signature field to sign the form!\nThis will automatically save the form!", 3);
    
        //Enable the field
        this.getField("signature1").readonly = false;
        this.getField("signature1").display = display.visible;

        //Set focus
        this.getField("signature1").setFocus();

        //Disable the save button
        this.getField("btn_sign").readonly = true;
    }
}
```

Here you see that after some sanity checks the field `signature1` is made active (not read-only anymore), visible, and in-focus. At the same time the button itself is made inactive (read-only).

Similarly the JavaScript code executed when `btn_sign2` is clicked, makes `signature2` active, visible, and in-focus, and `btn_sign2` itself inactive.

To determine this interaction between button fields and signature fields in your document, you have to analyze the associated JavaScript code.

You can retrieve the JavaScript code from a button field with iText 7 / Java like this:

```java
try (
    InputStream resource = getClass().getResourceAsStream("form_field_document.pdf");
    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(resource);
    PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfReader);
) {
    PdfAcroForm pdfAcroForm = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfDocument, false);
    PdfFormField btnSignField = pdfAcroForm.getField("btn_sign");
    PdfDictionary actionDictionary = btnSignField.getWidgets().get(0).getAction();
    if (PdfName.JavaScript.equals(actionDictionary.getAsName(PdfName.S))) {
        PdfObject jsObject = actionDictionary.get(PdfName.JS, true);
        if (jsObject instanceof PdfString) {
            System.out.print(((PdfString)jsObject).getValue());
        } else if (jsObject instanceof PdfStream) {
            PdfStream jsStream = (PdfStream)jsObject;
            System.out.print(new String(jsStream.getBytes()));
        }
    }
}
```

*([ReadButtonAction](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/form/ReadButtonAction.java#L35) test `testReadSignButtonAction`)*